# Monorepo - How to import from within and from without the package?

Tags: typescript, import, monorepo, tsconfig-paths

Yo. I have a question, that doesn't have a difinitive answer, but I would like to see the opinions of the community.

Let's say we have a Monorepo, with the following structure:

```
|--packageA
|----components
|------componentA.tsx
|------componentB
|----utils
|------UtilA.ts
|------UtilB.ts
|----index.ts
|--packageB
|----components
|------componentA.tsx
|------componentB
|----utils
|------UtilA.ts
|------UtilB.ts
|----index.ts
```

When we are in `packageA` and we import from `packageB`, we have TS_Paths and we do the following:

```
import { UtilB } from "@org/packageB"
```

Now, here is the question. When we want to import from inside the same package, either A or B, I wouldn't use absolute paths, to avoid issues like ciruclar dependancies and conflicting project graphs, and allowing every possible import path craziness. That being said, in my current organisation, this pattern is used inside the same project.

```
//componentA in packagaA
import {UtilsA} from "@org/packageA/utils"
```

Can someone explain the pros and cons, with some degree of detail?

Answer (score 0):

Where are your `tsconfig.json` files? Where are your `package.json` files? Where are the `node_modules/` located?

It sounds like your org is pretending it has many packages when in fact it just has one, and it is allowing circular dependencies, which will complicate your build with confused module resolution.

There is codesmell here, in that your imports should look like

```
import {UtilsA} from "@packageA/utils"
```

unless your team intended on the package being named `@org`

Or just... use multiple repos. Configuration for your tooling will often work out-of-the-box, it's easier to conform your CI and deploys to a 12 factor app, and you can isolate changes and incrementally upgrade portions of your system.